# json.dumps throws UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, json

I had *unknown encoding* in a MS ACCESS data table because the text inputs originated by people copying and pasting from Word documents.

So when I attempted:

```
final_data_to_write = json.dumps(list_of_text_lines)
```

The error output was:

```
 "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position 5: unexpected end of data"
```

Comment: I'd start by using a text editor with encoding support (such as Notepad++) to convert the CSV to ASCII and see if the problem persists. Another approach would be to use the Codecs module (the encode() method) and set the parameter "errors" to "ignore", so the codec problem stops being a fatal error and you can visualize your JSON output to see if there's something in the data that's messing the codec.

Comment: @ Rafael Almeida . Thanks. This seems to be working so far-->row1 = unicode( lines1[j] , errors='ignore')

Comment: """I had unknown encoding in a MS ACCESS data table because the text inputs originated by people copying and pasting from Word documents.""" -- hard to believe. Blowing away data is **NOT** a fix, it's a **FAIL**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop over the text lines and encode each one as follows:

```
row1 = unicode( list_of_text_line[j] , errors='ignore')
```

Comment: I think the problem arose because data entry of different text entries into MS ACCESS was done by people from all around the world sending in text files....I am not sure...but it looks like I may have fixed the isssue by forcing encoding of all strings to unicode( lines1[j] , errors='ignore') and ignoring problematic parts of the data. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You need to find out what character encoding is used in your database. Then you need to tell JSON encoder to use that encoding to properly interpret strings.

```
final_data_to_write = json.dumps(myDict, encoding="XXX")
```

Default encoding assumed by json module is UTF-8.

Answer (score 2):

The conversion from Access to Excel should have preserved your data as Unicode. If all the Unicode text is encodable in your "ANSI code page" (probably cp1252, but don't guess), then you won't have mangled anything by doing Excel "save-as-CSV" --- if not, you'd get `?` characters replacing the non-encodable characters. These wouldn't cause your current problem.

Things to do:

(1) Find out what is your "ANSI code page":

On my machine:

```
command_prompt>\python27\python -c"import locale;print locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,'')"
English_Australia.1252
```

So mine is `cp1252`.

(2) Try `json.dumps(myDict, encoding='cpXXXX')`

(3) If that fails, you need to look at your data and your CSV-to-JSON code to see if you are mangling something somewhere. Insert some debugging code to output the line numbers of any lines that contain any non-ASCII characters -- the test for that is `any(c >= '\x80' for c in line)` -- and look at those lines in a text editor and check if they make sense in your environment.